# Getting record elements dynamically apex:dataTable

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is that the salesforce documentation says about **apex:dataTable**:

> The first element in the iteration visibly rendered in the table,
>   where 0 is the index of the first element in the set of data specified
>   by the value attribute. For example, if you did not want to display
>   the first two elements in the set of records specified by the value
>   attribute, set first="2".

How can I get this elements dynamically (using a variable for example)?

Answer (score 3):

One of the approach, bind variable with controller:

```
    <apex:page controller="dataTableCon" id="thePage">

    <apex:dataTable value="{!accounts}" var="account" id="theTable" first="{!offset}" styleClass="tableClass">
            <apex:facet name="caption">table caption</apex:facet>

            <apex:facet name="header">table header</apex:facet>

            <apex:facet name="footer">table footer</apex:facet>

            <apex:column>

                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>

                <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>

                <apex:outputText value="{!account.name}"/>

            </apex:column>

            <apex:column>

                <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>

                <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>

                <apex:outputText value="{!account.owner.name}"/>

            </apex:column>

        </apex:dataTable>



<apex:commndbutton rerender="TheTable" value="Rerender Table" action="{!setOffset}"/>

    </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
class dataTableCon {
   public offset {get; set;}
   public void setOffset()
   {
      // doSomething
      offset = "5" // whatever
   }
}
```